# Incluir ícones nos botões do modal

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

Boa tarde, estou criando um modal que está já está com todas as funcionalidades perfeitas, porém preciso incluir nos botões os ícones de aceito e cancelar pra deixar mais didático para o usuário, porém em jquery não sei como fazer isso. O código que estou utilizando para chamar o modal é este, não sei se existe outra maneira de fazer isso tbm.

```
$('#div_dialog_MostrarTexto').dialog({
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").remove();
    },
    resizable: false,
    minHeight: 600,
    minWidth: 650,
    maxHeight: 600,
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: true,
    title: titulo,
    position: { my: 'top', at: 'top' },
    overflow: scroll,
    buttons: [
        {
            text: $('#doc_aceita_' + dadosDocumentos[idDocumento]).val(),
            disabled: false,
            image: "../img/confirmar.jpg",
            click: function() {
                aceitou(idDocumento);
            }
        },
        {
            text: $('#doc_recusa_' + dadosDocumentos[idDocumento]).val(),
            disabled: false,
            image: "../img/cancelar.jpg",
            click: function() {
                recusou(idDocumento);
            }
        },
    ]
});
```

Comment: Você pode criar um botão no HTML e personalizar o background com CSS, não precisaria de jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque não trabalha com ícones do jquery?

Se for com ícones segue, vou pesquisar sobre imagens.

```js
$('#div_dialog_MostrarTexto').dialog({
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").remove();
    },
    resizable: false,
    minHeight: 600,
    minWidth: 650,
    maxHeight: 600,
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: true,
    title: titulo,
    position: { my: 'top', at: 'top' },
    overflow: scroll,
    buttons: [
        {
            text: $('#doc_aceita_' + dadosDocumentos[idDocumento]).val(),
            disabled: false,
            icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-check' },
            click: function() {
                aceitou(idDocumento);
            }
        },
        {
            text: $('#doc_recusa_' + dadosDocumentos[idDocumento]).val(),
            disabled: false,
            icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-close' },
            click: function() {
                recusou(idDocumento);
            }
        },
    ]
});
```

Comment: Acredito que ele precise de uma variedade ícones maior, com outras cores e etc.

Comment: Então trabalhe com fontawesome, ficar fazendo imagens é trabalhoso... ou crie diversos ícones, compile e tenha personalizado.

Comment: Muito obrigado, resolveu o meu problema. No meu caso eu não precisaria de mais icones não, as opções sempre serão de sim ou não, porém com o texto de cada uma diferente a cada vez que abrir, agradeço a atenção de ambos!